# React jsx attribute avoid duplicate attribute name

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx

I am using Nextjs
I dont really know to describe my question but here is an example.

In my code, I got few

```
const pathname = router.pathname
<NavItem pathname={pathname} ... />
```

Is there a way to avoid that kind a duplicate name? To make it shorter? like this may be

```
<NavItem {pathname} ... />
```

I dont know if its possible but it's not the first time that I am looking for the kind of writing style

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of accomplishing that is using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). It may be overkill for one prop, but it can be useful for many.

---

You first define an object like this.

```js
const { pathname } = router;
const shortened = {
  pathname,
};
```

Let's see it line by line.

The first line is using [object destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the `pathname` key from `router`. This will simplify the object written later.

The second-to-fourth lines define an object called `shortened` (or whatever you want to call it). Inside of it, we pass in `pathname` as both a key and value in one (like a 2-in-1). This simply is a shorthand way of saying `pathname: pathname`.

Now, let's move on to the JSX!

---

Let's use the JSX here, and see what it does.

```html
<NavItem {...shortened} />
```

Basically, add that it is doing is using the spread syntax (`...`) to *"spread"* the object so that it looks like this when parsed.

```html
<NavItem pathname={pathname} />
```

So, it is just getting the key and value and spreading it out like that.

---

You can also add more keys and values to your object, without changing your JSX as well, which makes it easier and faster to type! It also may look better (depending on who you are).

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. I didn't approach the problem like that. It might help depending of the context because it look overkill for just 1 prop

Comment: Yes, it depends on that. But I can see that you have multiple props since you have an ellipsis on your JSX. But, React doesn't have a feature like you described. You just have to find a workaround. 

Comment: But, again, for multiple props, it might make it shorter and more readable.

Comment: You can add a suggestion on their [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues) using an Issue.

Comment: May be included in a future syntax. I will ask them :-)